# Typescript instanceof operator does not work for class that extends Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class

I have an app in node.js with `typescript` and `express.js`, compiled with `ts-node` in node `v18.14.0` and trying to handle the errors I ran into this problem and I can't quite understand why it happens and how to get to the expected result.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(message?: string) {
    super(message);
  }
}

const err = new CustomError('unauth');

console.log(err instanceof CustomError); // false in node.js
```

I don't understand why it returns 'true' in a react app with vite.js (as expected) and 'false' in a node.js app. And how can I check if the 'err' object was created with the 'CustomError' class?

Comment: Please post your tsconfig and the version of typescript that you have installed. Also look at the transpiled, actually executed, code; the issue should become obvious then.

Answer (score 0):

In case of es5 output, it will not work but I believe changing output will change lot's of thing. What you can do here is to override the name property like this:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  name = "CustomError";
  constructor(message?: string) {
    super(message);
  }
}

const err = new CustomError('unauth');

console.log(err.name === "CustomError");
```

For better code maintainability, you should use constant to store the name error like this:

```
const CUSTOM_ERROR = "CustomError"
class CustomError extends Error {
  name = CUSTOM_ERROR;
  constructor(message?: string) {
    super(message);
  }
}

const err = new CustomError('unauth');

console.log(err.name === CUSTOM_ERROR);
```

Comment: No need. The correct solution is just to not use ES5 output for node.js

Comment: So do you think only changing output in tsconfig will enough?
Also for this single use case, I don't think we should take a risk at this level. I believe these type of changes should go through a proper channel.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. There is no reason to support legacy output that deviates from the standard behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is extensively covered in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10166) and covered in the [TypeScript 2.1 breaking changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/main/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work). In short, you shouldn't try to extend built-in classes when using any transpiler that emits ES5 code. This includes non-TypeScript transpilers like Babel too.

The easiest solution is to just not compile to ES5. The difference between your browser and node.js code is probably that the browser transpilation was outputting ES6 while your node.js one was using ES5 for some reason. If you actually need to support ES5, then the breaking change note linked above has a solution: manually use `Object.setPrototypeOf()` inside the constructor to set `this`'s prototype to itself:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(message?: string) {
    super(message);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomError.prototype);
  }
}

const err = new CustomError('unauth');
console.log(err instanceof CustomError); // => true
```